# How to check if input value is an image or not?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to take the input string and verify whether an image exists on the URL.

**When I click the 'Check' button, the intended result is to validate whether the input value is a regex match. If it is or is not, display an appropriate result.**

**JS**

```
checkImage.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let url = document.getElementById("inputUrl").value;
  // console.log(url);

  if (typeof url !== "string") result.textContent = "This is not an image";
  return url.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/) != null;

  result.textContent;
});
```

```js
checkImage.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let url = document.getElementById("inputUrl").value;
  // console.log(url);

  if (typeof url !== "string") result.textContent = "This is not an image";
  return url.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/) != null;

  result.textContent;
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" id="inputUrl" placeholder="url of image">
  <button type="button" id="checkImage">Check</button>
</form>

<h3 id="result">?</h3>
```

Comment: you are returning before `isImage` is being called

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: So what is `isImage`?

Comment: *"How can I get this function to work? What am I missing?"* What does not work???

Comment: When the button "Check" is clicked, I want to verify if the values jpg, jpeg, gif or png exist within the input value. If they do, then output a result. I thought the question was clear. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `return`ing from the event handler before anything is put in the result div.

A few other notes.

- using [`regex.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) is the appropriate method for testing if a string matches a pattern. The `match` method you used, although it will work, is intended for extracting parts of a string.
- Your `url` variable will *always* be a string as the value of an input, so checking that is unnecessary.

```js
var checkImage = document.getElementById("checkImage");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

checkImage.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let url = document.getElementById("inputUrl").value;
  var is_image =  /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/.test(url);
  result.textContent = is_image ? 'valid image' : 'invalid';
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" id="inputUrl" placeholder="url of image">
  <button type="button" id="checkImage">Check</button>
</form>

<h3 id="result">?</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

You always `return` before you set the textContent.

It's not clear what the `isImage` does, but it seems redundant because you've already checked the URL in the event handler.

Maybe this is more like what you intended:

```js
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var checkImage = document.getElementById("checkImage");
checkImage.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let url = document.getElementById("inputUrl").value;
  console.log(url, typeof url);

  if (typeof url !== "string") result.textContent = "This is not an image";
  if (url.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/) != null) {
    result.textContent = "Yes";
  }
  else
  {
    result.textContent = "No";
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" id="inputUrl" placeholder="url of image">
  <button type="button" id="checkImage">Check</button>
</form>

<h3 id="result">?</h3>
```

---

N.B. Note that this approach simply checks whether the URL ends with a file extension used by popular image formats. It does not check whether the resource returned by that URL actually *is* an image (and may also exclude some URLs which return image data but have a different URL format).

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are returning before calling this  `result.textContent = isImage(url);` whatever that does